# same url_prefix for two flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask, routes

I want to implement simple site layout:

`/` must render `home.html`

`/one`, `/two`, `/three` must render `one.html`, `two.html`, `three.html` correspondingly

So far I came up with following code:

```py
main_page = Blueprint('main', __name__)
category_page = Blueprint('category', __name__)


@main_page.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@category_page.route('/<category>')
def show(category):
    return render_template('{}.html'.format(category))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(main_page, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(category_page, url_prefix='/categories')
```

This way I am able to route `categories` to `/categories/<category>`. How can I route them to just `/<category>` instead, while keeping `home.html` linked to `/`? Appreciate your help

I tried two approaches:

1. Setting `url_prefix='/'` for both blueprints => second one does not work.
2. Instead of `main_page` blueprint use just `app.route('/')` to render `home.html`. This one also does not work when mixing with `category_page` blueprint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the variable to the `url_prefix` parameter inside the registering statement :

```
@main_page.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
app.register_blueprint(main_page, url_prefix='/')

@category_page.route('/')
def show(category):
    return render_template('{}.html'.format(category))        
app.register_blueprint(category_page, url_prefix='/<category>')
```

(it depends on the complexity of the whole pattern, but it may be better to keep the registering statements with the variables close to each function to handle many views.)

Comment: Thank you so much! That was almost too easy :)

Comment: i agree, you kinda made all the work here!! i like the pattern, even if it may be inconvenient to handle many routes and many variables, unless you keep the registering part close from the function